# When should I use `common/esm5/http` VS `http/esm5/http`

Tags: angular

I'm encountering two HTTP packages from angular latest where webpack sees 2 different versions/sources.

While investigating  , I found that they come from different locations :

- `@angular/common/esm5/http.ja`
- `@angular/http/esm5/http.js`

[image]

**Question:**

What is the difference between those two resources ? I'm using Angular 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code youre referencing the now deprecated [HTTP module](https://angular.io/api/http/HttpModule).

You should migrate this code over to the `@angular/common/http` package. Details can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Do a quick scan in the codebase for this import:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Those are the areas impacted.

Comment: I know about the new 4.3 version. And I do use `import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";`.  But  I think i've found the culprit   : https://i.imgur.com/JMkmbNr.jpg

Comment: Hmm something is importing it though

Answer (score 1):

`@angular/common/esm5/http.js` is the file where is defined the new version of `Angular/http` module. It comes with awesome news such us Interceptors and new router life cycle events for Guards and Resolvers. (it was defined in Angular 4.3 version)

```
`@angular/http/esm5/http.js`
```

is the older version, however you can still use it in Angular 5 but you are missing out the new powerful features.

[Angular 4.3 what is new](https://blog.angular.io/angular-4-3-now-available-8d57b57eb5a8)